# Is it possible to have Read and Update inside the same View using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I mean I have a project for inventory control. I wanted to create a single page where I could display the items and aside of the item I would have buttons like Update and Delete. When, say, Update is clicked a popup would appear (in the same page, just like when you open a website and there's that block telling you about cookies, or any promotion of the website you're surfing in).

My tries so far:

1. Javascript ->

```
const handleUpdate = (url) => {

     const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
     url='localhost:8000';
     Http.open("POST", url);
     Http.send();

     Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
         console.log(Http.responseText)
     }
 }
```

> So when I click the button I would get the returned object. I know. Terrible.

2. Quantum List -> While typing I thought: What if I created a form for every single model?!

> Yeah... 300+ IQ... And if I had like a thousand entries my html would be just like one of those physics book about the quantum universe.

**So question is: How would you go about that? And actually is there a way of doing it?**

PS: I already did the modal part with HTML/CSS. I want to know how to display the list of the items and when clicking in a item update button a modal form would show up with the item's fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved through [django-bootstrap-modal-forms](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-modal-forms/)

Please have a look at the Demo and Documentation in the link. It is pretty straight forward.